# почему min и max находят не самое маленькое и большое числа?

Tags: python, max, min

мне нужно указать минимальный и максимальный рост среди группы. Почему-то функции min и max работают не совсем корректно. Если я впишу сильно отличающиеся числа, к примеру 20 1000 5000 10000, мне выдаст, что min и max 1000 и 5000. Что, как и почему?

```
height = input('введите рост участников группы без запятой: ').split()
min(height), max(height)
```

Comment: Потому что это не числа, а строки, `height` это список строк

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую прочитать про то как min() и max() работают со строками.

В твоем случае правильным ответом будет преобразование каждого элемента сплита в число:

```
height = [int(h) for h in input('введите рост участников группы без запятой: ').split()]
```

`int(h)` это если ожидаются только целые числа. Если дробные - заменяешь `int(h)` на `float(h)`, только учти, что дробное делается через точку (`5.1`, к примеру).